# Cannot find name 'Map'. Do you need to change your target library?

Tags: typescript

Upon executing the command `tsc app.ts`, an error is generated with the following message.

```
error TS2583: Cannot find name 'Map'. Do you need to change your target library? Try changing the lib compiler option to es2015 or later.
```

My desired outcome is for the code to compile flawlessly and for the import statement to function properly.

Comment: _"Do you need to change your target library? Try changing the lib compiler option to es2015 or later."_ - ...did you? Give a [mre].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run **tsc main.ts**, your **tsconfig.json** file is not being used. Instead run **tsc -p** or simply **tsc**.